# Pythontex couldnt find engine

Tags: python, pythontex

I tried to use pythontex in my LaTeX Program. Therefore i installed MikTex an working with Texmaker. There i installed the pythontex-package (by installing it via usepackage).
After running the pdflatex, there isn't showing any of the Python-Code. I tried to run "pythontech [name].tex" in cmd but get the error:

pythontex: The script engine could not be found.
pythontex: Data: scriptEngine="python.exe", scriptName="pythontex"

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Judging from the error message... perhaps you need to install [Python](https://www.python.org/)?

Comment: I have Python installed on my Laptop. Do i have to install it somewhere specific or have to set the path anywhere (in latex or somewhere else?).

Comment: I've hardly used PythonTeX and it wasn't under Windows, so... But I'd start with checking that `python.exe` is in your `PATH`. Can you successfully run `python.exe` from a command prompt (`cmd.exe`)?

Comment: I have added it to my Path now, so I can run python from the command prompt.
The Problem is that when I now try to run pythontex, I get this errors:

  File "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts/pythontex\pythontex.py", line 50, in <module>
    import pythontex2 as pythontex
  File "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex2.py", line 61, in <module>
    from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
ImportError: No module named pygments.styles

Comment: You probably need to install `pygments` for the Python installation. Something like `python.exe -m pip install pygments` (or `py -m pip install pygments` or a variant, in case you have several Python installations—without further info, I'll assume you don't).

Comment: Just found it out myself and installed it. Thank you so much!!